# Adding Custom Fields To Collections

Tags: shopify, custom-fields

I'm pretty new to the shopify platform but I was wondering if anyone could confirm for me if you can add custom fields to collections in Shopify? I've seen that metafields2 might be an option but the only examples I'm seeing are for products. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: no that is not a feature of shopify

Comment: Great, thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can add metafields in the collection.

See a full list of the types that support metafields in here: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield

You can do a simple test with the `ShopifyFD` ( there is an chome extension  ) that will provide the metafield interface that you can add/remove/modify metafields.

And Metafields2 support metafields on collection as well. ( as well as all other types )